# IF/ELSE em SQL (Estruturas de controle)

Tags: sql

Certo, estou lendo alguns artigos sobre estruturas de controle em SQL porém não estou sacando muita coisa não, alguém poderia explicar como funciona de uma forma resumida?

Comment: Qual é a condição que você quer testar? apresente o seu código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu costumo usar a clausula When ao inves de IF, porem....

Funciona parecido com as estruturas de programação de outras linguagens.

No SQL Server, a instrução IF ... ELSE é usada para executar o código quando uma condição é TRUE ou executar um código diferente se a condição for avaliada como FALSE.

Nada melhor que umas linhas de codigo para ver o funcionamento

```
DECLARE @teste INT;
SET @teste = 15;

IF @teste < 20
   PRINT 'Acertou';
ELSE
   PRINT 'ERRRROU';
GO
```

RETORNO: Acertou

Como pode ver ele trouxe o acertou porque entrou na primeira condição verdadeira de que o teste que vale 15 e menor (<) do que 20

de uma forma resumida é isso....

bom link de analise;
https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/loops/if_then.php

Caso queira saber sobre o WHEN 
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

A linguagem SQL propriamente dita não possui um comando IF/ELSE.
Você encontrará tal comando em linguagens procedimentais associadas ao seu gerenciador de banco de dados.
Em SQL você pode utilizar a condional CASE/WHEN:

```
CASE WHEN condition THEN result
     [WHEN ...]
     [ELSE result]
END
```

Em alguns casos as funções COALESCE e NULLIF podem atender a suas necessidades.